# Rails mass assignment issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I know this question has been asked a lot, but the solution usually proposed was to set `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes` to false. I've tried that, and still get this 
issue:

`Can't mass-assign protected attributes: ingredient_attributes`

I have two models: **recipe.rb** and **ingredient.rb**. They have a one to many relationship, where each recipe can have many ingredients.

**recipe.rb**

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :description, :name, :yield, :recipe_id

    has_many :ingredient, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient
end
```

**ingredient.rb**

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :recipe
    attr_accessible :ingredient, :listorder, :recipe_id
end
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why have you declared `:recipe_id` `attr_accessible` in your `Recipe` model?

Comment: I think I had read that was a solution to the mass assignment issue, but it didn't work so I can probably take it out.

Comment: The error message you're receiving is indicative of a one-to-one relationship, not a one-to-many. However, your models look correct. Maybe something is fishy with the processing of your form... can you post your controller and view?

Comment: Controller:http://codepad.org/HrntKhHT

Comment: the partial that I'm using for the view: http://codepad.org/hcoG7BFK

Comment: See updated answer. If it's correct, I'd encourage you to amend your post to include the relevant lines of code from your view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pluralize `:ingredient` in your `Recipe` class:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :ingredients, :dependent => :destroy
    attr_accessible :description, :name, :yield, :recipe_id, :ingredients_attributes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end
```

EDIT:

As I suspected, the issue causing the `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: ingredient_attributes` error is related to [your view](http://codepad.org/hcoG7BFK).

On line 18, you're invoking a `fields_for` block for `:ingredient`, which creates a form for a `has_one` child relationship. However, since a recipe actually `has_many` ingredients, you *should* really be using `:ingredients`:

```
# app/views/recipe/form.html.erb
<%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |builder|%> # Line 18 in http://codepad.org/hcoG7BFK
```

Comment: Do I need to pluralize the has_many too? I got this error `No association found for name ingredients. Has it been defined yet?`

Comment: Ok, I've done that, but the mass assignment error is still there?

Comment: Explicitly declare `ingredient_attributes` as `attr_accessible`. See the updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the help but now I'm getting `unknown attribute: ingredient_attributes`

Comment: Since it's one-to-many relationship, you may need to add an 's' to 'ingredient': `attr_accessible :ingredients_attributes`. Updated to reflect.

Comment: Okay, I added an s to ingredient but it's still saying `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: ingredient_attributes`. Do I need to change my model names to plural versions?

Comment: Model declarations should __always__ be singular in OOP. The problem you're having is evidently related to your view, rather than your model. I've amended my answer to provide a potential fix – please inform as to whether or not it works.

Comment: thank you so much for all your help. You really have gone above and beyond with this answer, thank you!